# How can i list all name when it matches anywhere in the string?

Tags: android, xml

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    String nameMapString = XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name");
    if(nameMapString.matches(".*+searchTextString1+.*")){
        map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
        map.put("name", "Name:" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
        map.put("Score", "Score: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "score"));
        mylist.add(map);
    }


}
```

I am writing an android program.
searchTextString is user provided value from EditText.
nameMapString holds value of name tag from xml file.
Suppose it may contain Mark, Marry, Jack, JackMar etc.
When i search Ma only, i want to display all which contain Ma (in this case Mark,Marry,JackMar). but above code display all name.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782701/how-to-add-textwatcher-to-activity-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `indexOf(String str)` method for it, see the updated code below,

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
{
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    String nameMapString = XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name");
    if ( nameMapString.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTextString1.toLowerCase()) != -1 )   // != -1 means string is present in the search string
    {
        map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
        map.put("name", "Name:" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
        map.put("Score", "Score: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "score"));
        mylist.add(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx dude, It Work Great ! But how do i ignorecase Letters. Eg: provides same result for Mark and mark

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it again, now it will work with ignore case